# Is it possible to run "@@solr-maintenance/reindex" script through terminal or cronjob?

Tags: python, linux, solr, plone

I am using `collective.solr` with Plone and I can run different scripts like `"reindex"` through the browser.

But I would like to create a cronjob and run it through the terminal.

**Question**

Is it possible to run "@@solr-maintenance/reindex" script through terminal or cronjob?

Comment: You should ask this in our forum, https://community.plone.org. Please see https://plone.org/support on how to best get help with Plone